# My Post request is going to the Page Expired page on production server

Tags: laravel, post, production-environment

I am new to laravel. i have recently finished one project with laravel and uploaded it on the production server. all done successfully but i am facing and issue now . when i try to login and send the post request it always goes to 419 page expired page. also the same problem when i try to login to the admin area on the same application it gives me CSRF mismatch error. i am trying to login with the help of AJAX to the backend of the same application.

I am using laravel version 5.8.*. it works well with http but when i moved this over production server ie. on https domain it is sending me to the page expired page when i try to enter the credentials and login to the app.

If you know why it is happening then please tell me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my html  code :-

```
<form action="<?php echo url('admin/checkLogin'); ?>" class="col-lg-12" id="admin_sign_in_form"
                      method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger loginerror" style="display: none;"><i
                                class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> wrong credential.
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="alert alert-success loginsuccess" style="display: none;"><i
                                class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> wrong credential.
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                    </div>

                    <h5 class="title">Sign in to your Account</h5>
                    <div class="form-group-pvr form-float">
                        <div class="form-line-pvr">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                            <label class="form-label">Email</label>
                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                            <span class="admin_email_err text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group-pvr form-float">
                        <div class="form-line-pvr">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
                            <label class="form-label">Password</label>
                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                            <span class="admin_pass_err text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{-- <div class="form-check pull-left">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                            <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div> --}}

                    <div class="col-lg-12 m-t-10">
                        {{--<a href="#"  id="admin_sign_in_btn" class="btn btn-purple waves-effect">Sign In</a>--}}
                        <button type="submit" id="adminLoginBtn" class="btn btn-purple btn-block waves-effect">Login</button>
                    </div>
                    {{--<div class="col-lg-12 m-t-20">--}}
                        {{--<a class="" href="pvr_forgot_password.html">Forgot Password?</a>--}}
                    {{--</div>--}}
                </form>
```

Here is my Ajax code :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#admin_sign_in_form").on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var error = 0;
            let adminemail = $("#email").val();
            let adminpassword = $("#password").val();

             if(adminemail == ''){
                 error++;
                 // $('.admin_email_err').html("Please Enter email");
             }else{
                 // $('.admin_email_err').html("");
             }

             if(adminpassword == ''){
                 error++;
                 // $('.admin_pass_err').html("Please Enter password");
             }else{
                 // $('.admin_pass_err').html("");
             }

            if(error==0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo url('/admin/checkLogin'); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success:function(data){
                        if(data['code']==200){
                            //alert(data['code']);
                            //$('#loginform').trigger("reset");
                            $('.loginerror').css('display','none');
                            $('.loginsuccess').html(data['msg']).css('display','block');
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                window.location.href = '<?php echo url('admin/dashboard'); ?>';
                            }, 1500);
                        }
                        if(data['code']==100){
                            $('.loginerror').html(data['msg']).css('display','block');
                            $('.formvalid').html("Invalid username and password");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I am sending the whole formdata along with the ajax request and i have added the csrf_field as well. Please check.

Comment: Please give us more details about your code. I assume that your AJAX request not sending CSRF token, same as your login form.

Comment: hello i have edited my question please check and let me know where i am wrong. i am new to laravel.

Comment: in laravel 419 error is basiclly csrf token error make sure all post data you have to put that

Comment: please check in my HTML i have added the csrf field and it shows me on the ajax post data.

Comment: Hey @PranaySute did you try the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

your ajax code is fine as you said its working on local environment. Actually your server is not permanently caching/storing new files being generated like session file. No persisting session means no csrf validation...

Try using database as your session driver.

1. Create table for session using `php artisan session:table`
2. On your server environment file change SESSION_DRIVER from file to database and config cache on server. **If server doesnot have env file change the default session driver in config/session.php**

This will store the session info to database table that you created on step 1.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#driver-prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some solution that each one can be the solution of your problem:

1.See in `Inspect` of your browser that token is created for csrf hidden input or not.if that input has null input,set token manually with `{{csrf_token}}` in anyway you know(for example with jquery when page is load).

2.Use `{!! csrf_field() !!}` instead of `{{csrd_field()}}` works in some case

3.Go to `session.php` in `config folder` and find `domain` and change it to your domain name.

4.Set `['middleware' => ['web']]` for your route.

I hope one of these solution works for you